# Uninstaller sometimes leaves behind some files

Tags: windows, windows-registry, uninstall

Sometimes even if you run the uninstaller some files get left behind, usually in the registry. How to make sure all the program-related files I want to uninstall are removed for good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a program like Your Uninstaller or Revo Uninstaller.

These utilities will allow you to uninstall a program plus search for left over files and reg entries to make sure the system is clean from the program.

http://alternativeto.net/software/your-uninstaller/